# Reshape a list of dataframes using columns index

Tags: r, reshape

I have a list of several dataframes with 3 columns each and I want to reshape them all. Each data frame has different columns names (I have tried to change the colnames for all df without success, but that is another SO question :)), so I must index the columns rather than use column names.

I can get what I want using lapply:

```
df = lapply(df, function(x) reshape(x, v.names = 1, idvar = 3, timevar = 2, direction ="wide"))
```

Where 1,2 and 3 are the df columns I want to use. But out of curiosity I tried to do the same using a for loop, but I can´t get it right.

```
for (i in length(df)){
df[[i]] <- reshape(df[[i]], v.names = 1, idvar = 3, timevar = 2, direction = "wide")
}
```

This doesn´t do anything. I am not sure how to specify the columns, given that i cannot use column names. For example:

```
for (i in length(df)){
df[[i]] <- reshape(df[[i]], v.names = df[[i]][,1], idvar = df[[i]][,3], timevar = df[[i]][,2], direction = "wide")
}

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , idvar) : undefined columns selected
```

So, how can I reshape a list of data frames with a for loop using columns indices? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your code

```
for (i in length(df))
```

this will only pass once for i = the last member of the list. Just try to put `length(df)` to the console - it just outputs one number. You want a vector of numbers 1, 2, ..., length(df), so you want `1:length(df)`:

```
for (i in 1:length(df))
```

Another option (as @*boat noted) is `seq_along(df)`. This is more safe - in case `df` is not defined it will produce empty vector, unlike the method above. But I prefer the above notation much more, it's just a matter of context and personal preference.

Comment: Or `for (i in seq_along(df))` which is safer since the option you offer fails with length-0 situations.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot of this - this is a safer variant of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to address the two issues (reshaping and changing name of list of df).

```
data(Indometh)
names(Indometh)
## [1] "Subject" "time"    "conc"

### create a list of df
dflist <- lapply(1:3, function(x) Indometh)

### changing the name of df
dflist <- lapply(dflist, setNames,
                 c("subject", "timevar", "conc"))

### Reshaping the data using colnames
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(df)
                 reshape(df,
                         v.names = "conc",
                         idvar = "subject",
                         timevar = "timevar",
                         direction = "wide")
                 )

str(dflist, max.level = 1)
## List of 3
##  $ :Classes ‘nfnGroupedData’, ‘nfGroupedData’, ‘groupedData’ and 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  12 variables:
##   ..- attr(*, "reshapeWide")=List of 5
##  $ :Classes ‘nfnGroupedData’, ‘nfGroupedData’, ‘groupedData’ and 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  12 variables:
##   ..- attr(*, "reshapeWide")=List of 5
##  $ :Classes ‘nfnGroupedData’, ‘nfGroupedData’, ‘groupedData’ and 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  12 variables:
##   ..- attr(*, "reshapeWide")=List of 5
```